# Is it possible to display foreign tables (Oracle to PostGIS) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, oracle-dbms

I have used [oracle_fdw](http://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/) to create a [foreign data wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) in my PostgreSQL database to connect to my Oracle database and retrieve  foreign tables from the Oracle database into my Postgres database. This includes the geometry of the Oracle table.

When I save the foreign table as a "local" table and add a primary key and spatial index, I can add the local table to the map in QGIS, so I know that the geometry has been retrieved correctly.

However, when I try to put the foreign table directly into QGIS, I get "invalid layer and cannot be loaded". I'm sure that this is because I can't add  a spatial index or primary key to the foreign table.

Is there any way to show this foreign table in QGIS without the spatial index and primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Try making an editable view for this foreign table, if you need to see up-to-date data, and add this view to QGIS.